# Marmalade error download

Tags: url, interface, download, package, marmalade

i tried everything to solve this but since two days i'm blocked.
i need IwNui Api in my application to build interface for my application iOs, but when adding this package to the mkb project with this line 'subproject IwNUI', Visual studio block on this trace error :

```
    Building project: c:/Users/PC/Documents/testaaaa/testaaaa.mkb
1>c:/Users/PC/Documents/testaaaa/testaaaa.mkb(14): warning : filename case does not match the filesystem: c:/marmalade/6.2/modules/IwNUI/IwNUI.mkf
1>  Executing: 'c:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\bin\mdev.bat update'
1>  Downloading: http://source.madewithmarmalade.com/packages/6.2/Packages
1>  Downloading: https://raw.github.com/marmalade/mdev-package-list/master/6.2?1365852339.42
1>CUSTOMBUILD : error : error downloading url: https://raw.github.com/marmalade/mdev-package-list/master/6.2?1365852339.42 (<urlopen error (8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol')>)
1>c:/marmalade/6.2/modules/iwutil/iwutil.mkf(19): error : Executing 'c:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\bin\mdev.bat update' failed. (return code 1)
1>  FAILED (error code=3)
```

Even every examples of marmalde launchap which use Iw** api can't be build because the dowload of : https://raw.github.com/marmalade/mdev-package-list/master/6.2?1365852339.42 is not working.
I saw tips on some pages but these not fixed it for me (delete folder in roaming/appdata/marmalade , close firewall, try with old sdk 6.2.1,6.2.0,6.1 etc)

I'm open to every suggestions, my development was going well until i need an UI to going forward. I'm beginner in interface development and if a different and easy way exist for adding a Ios UI i'm also interested in.

Thanks a lot for reading, dams

Answer (score 0):

Marmalade needs the mdev package to function properly, thus you've to download it anyways, there're now way you can skip it. The problem is with your internet connection. Probably it's not accepting HTTPS connections. Try using some other internet provider or check using some friends' wifi. I always get this error when my internet is slow and the download gets timeout. Changing the internet plan is the only thing that might help.

In case it gives the same error on other internet connection, then it might be some issues with how you set up marmalade, Try reinstalling it.

Comment: thanks for replying so fastly, i'm working on fixe tower pc , i'm looking in this direction for allowing https download...
and on a second time i will install VS and marmalade on my portable for trying your trick.

ps : my internet is not slow, and i always have a good connection (ethernet actually)

Comment: This error is very random and always points towards internet issues or wrong configuration setup generally. Another thing you can try is downloading the package separately and put it into appdata, but I am not sure this will work. Worth a try.

Comment: Fixed!!! finally after 2 days! thanks a lot thanks to you i keep focused on my connection internet or settings of my computer.
Apparently there were an active proxy with internet explorer! i just untick a checkbox and everything works i build many mkb and all is fine!
i hope it will help many others users because i saw many tickets without answers

Comment: So the culprit was internet afterall ;-)

Comment: You can accept this answer, so as to help users who might have the same issue in future.